# What is compile-time encapsulation in C?

Tags: c

When I was researching the advantages of C over C++, I came across this paragraph:

> Standard way in C to do encapsulation is to forward declare a struct
>   and only allow access to its data through functions. This method also
>   creates compile time encapsulation. Compile time encapsulation allows
>   us to change the data structures members without recompilation of
>   client code (other code using our interface). The standard way of
>   doing encapsulation C++ on the other hand (using classes) requires
>   recompilation of client code when adding or removing private member
>   variables.

I understand how forward declaring a struct and accessing its members through functions hides the struct's implementation details. What I don't understand is this line specifically:

> Compile time encapsulation allows us to change the data structures
>   members **without recompilation of client code** (other code using our
>   interface).

In what scenario is this applicable?

Comment: Basically, the `struct` is a black box with unknown internals. If the client does not know the internals, it can never access them directly and you can change them at will.
This is similar to encapsulation in OOP. The internals are private and you only change the object using public methods.

Comment: This is not always true. If you decide to add/remove members of a struct, you change its size. This will require recompilation of the client code.

Comment: @DarkAtom Not true! If the client doesn't know the contents (an *opaque* structure), then it doesn't know its size, so changing the size isn't a problem.

Comment: @DarkAtom: Allowing access to a structure only through functions includes allocation only through functions. The library would provide a function to allocate a structure, and the client would never know its size. Changing the size does not require recompiling the client.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Also, a forward declaration of a `struct` allows pointers to be passed around, but doesn't allow passing that `struct` by value.   If only a pointer is passed around, the size of the structure is irrelevant.

Comment: Note that this is technically not an "advantage of C over C++" as you can (and often do) implement the same idea in C++. Look up the ["pimpl" idiom](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/pimpl.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible real-world scenario where this would occur is when a database library, written in the days when hard-disk space was very limited, used a single byte to store the 'year' field of a date (e.g. 11-NOV-1973 would have `73` for the year). But, when the Year 2000 came along, this would no longer be sufficient, and the year had then to be stored as a short (16-bit) integer. The relevant (much simplified) header for this library could be this:

```c
// dbEntry.h
typedef struct _dbEntry dbEntry;

dbEntry* CreateDBE(int day, int month, int year, int otherData);
void DeleteDBE(dbEntry* entry);
int GetYear(dbEntry* entry);
```

And a 'client' program would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dbEntry.h"

int main()
{
    int dataBlob = 42;
    dbEntry* test = CreateDBE(17, 11, 2019, dataBlob);
    //...
    int year = GetYear(test);
    printf("Year = %d\n", year);
    //...
    DeleteDBE(test);
    return 0;
}
```

The 'original' implementation:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dbEntry.h"

struct _dbEntry {
    unsigned char d;
    unsigned char m;
    unsigned char y;    // Fails at Y2K!
    int dummyData;
};

dbEntry* CreateDBE(int day, int month, int year, int otherData)
{
    dbEntry* local = malloc(sizeof(dbEntry));
    local->d = (unsigned char)(day);
    local->m = (unsigned char)(month);
    local->y = (unsigned char)(year % 100);
    local->dummyData = otherData;
    return local;
}

void DeleteDBE(dbEntry* entry)
{
    free(entry);
}

int GetYear(dbEntry* entry)
{
    return (int)(entry->y);
}
```

Then, at the approach of Y2K, this implementation file would be changed as follows (everything else being left untouched):

```c
struct _dbEntry {
    unsigned char d;
    unsigned char m;
    unsigned short y;   // Can now differentiate 1969 from 2069
    int dummyData;
};

dbEntry* CreateDBE(int day, int month, int year, int otherData)
{
    dbEntry* local = malloc(sizeof(dbEntry));
    local->d = (unsigned char)(day);
    local->m = (unsigned char)(month);
    local->y = (unsigned short)(year);
    local->dummyData = otherData;
    return local;
}
```

When the client needs to be updated to use the new (Y2K-safe) version, no code changes would be required. In fact, you *may* not even have to re-compile: simply ***re-linking*** to the updated object library (if that's what it is) *could be* sufficient.

Comment: This would happen only if the getter `int GetYear(dbEntry* entry);` is defined to return an `int`. It is highly likely that it would have been defined to return a `char`, isn't it? Then in multiple places of client code, the call to this function would be assigned to a `char`, which would have led to requiring code changes and recompilation on the client side as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: The following list will be non-exhaustive. Edits are welcome!*

The applicable scenarios include:

- Multi-module applications where you don't want recompilation for some reason.
- Structures used in libraries where you don't want to force the users of the library to recompile each time you change a (published) structure.
- Structures that contain different elements on the different platforms the module works on.

The most known structure of this kind is `FILE`. You just call `fopen()` and get a pointer if successful. This pointer is then handed over to each other function that works on files. But you don't know - and you don't want to know - the details, like contained elements and the size.